# boost geometry distance() error in compile

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, boost-geometry

I just write a simply example given by boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/quickstart.html). There are some errors during compiling. I use eclipse and Mingw to compile it. Could someone tell me what's the problem?

The test code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/distance.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; 
model::d2::point_xy<int> p1(1, 1), p2(2, 2);
cout << "Distance p1-p2 is: " << distance(p1, p2) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-  
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114:5:   
required by substitution of 'template<class _InputIterator> 
typename std::iterator_traits::difference_type 
std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator 
= boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>]'
..\src\test.cpp:22:50:   required from here
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-  
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:166:53: 
error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'class 
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>'
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:167:53: 
error: no type named 'value_type' in 'class   
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>'
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:168:53: 
error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'class  
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>'
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:169:53: 
error: no type named 'pointer' in 'class 
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>'
c:\program files\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-  
mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:170:53: 
error: no type named 'reference' in 'class 
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>'
```

Comment: This compiles fine under gcc-4.3.2 and today's clang from trunk, what compiler flags did you use?

Comment: I use gcc-4.7.1. Do you think that this problem arises from the version of gcc?

Comment: No idea, but might be. Are you sure your Boost version is recent enough to support your compiler?

Comment: I use the latest version of boost 1.52.0. how can I know whether it is recent enough or not?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. It seems that the boost support gcc-4.7.0. but it does not say about gcc-4.7.1.

Comment: Sorry, I have been test-compiling the wrong `test.cpp` here, take back that it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why you should be sparing with using-directives. You have:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::geometry;
```

dragging all the names within these namespaces into the global namespace. That includes both `std::distance` and `boost::geometry::distance` and (judging from the error message) `std::distance` was chosen as the better overload.

If you remove `using namespace std;`, and qualify with `std::` where necessary, then all should be fine. Alternatively, if you really want to keep the namespace pollution, then write the qualified name, `boost::geometry::distance`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! when I add "boost::geometry::"in front of distance. It works. Could you please tell me how to avoid this mistake? I don't want to add such long characters in every function all the time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1894177: The best way is not to use using-directives, or at least, to restrict them to a much narrower scope than the entire file.  Personally I never use `using namespace std;` (since `std::` is such a short prefix that it's not worth getting rid of); for a longer namespace, you could give it a short alias, e.g. `namespace geo = boost::geometry`.